# How can I say 'so'?

Tags: interjection

How can I say *so* in German? Like when there is a small silence or maybe someone deviates from the original topic and you interject? E.g. *So, where were we?* or *So, where are we going?* or even *So?* (after a silence or expecting an answer).

Comment: In German, this filling would just be omitted in most cases.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have more than one possibilities:

> So, where were we?
>
> - So, wo waren wir?
> - Also, wo waren wir?
> - Nun, wo waren wir?
> - Na, wo waren wir?
> - Okay, wo waren wir?

Same for *"So, where are we going?"*

> So?
>
> - Na?
> - Und?

Answer (score 4):

Just adding to Hubet Schölnast's (correct) answer, you will mostly want to use *also* for *so* at the beginning of a sentence. I know several English speakers who start their German sentences with *so* and (for some reason) I find it particularly jarring. *also* resumes the conversation at a point; *so* says "That's settled, then".